# Autofill lines based off cell value

Tags: vba, excel

First time poster here. I've been searching for an answer to my question, however I'm having trouble finding a similar situation with an answer that works for me. I'm using Excel VBA to try to solve a problem with work. I'm fairly new to the VBA environment so I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help or advice would be appreciated!

**The problem:**

I have a value in cell `B14` on Tab1. This cell has a `COUNT` formula which counts the number of values also on Tab1. With this number (for example, 14), I'd like it to go to Tab2 and copy the formula in cells `A2:H2` down the number shown in the cell, so 14 rows.

If `B14` shows 27, I'd like the macro to auto fill `A2:H2` 27 rows and so on. I've tried a few examples from similar questions but couldn't get it to work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the value in `B14` is determined via a formula, you'll need to monitor the `Worksheet_Calculate` event to determine when its value changes. A `Static` variable will do the trick. Add the following event handler to `Sheet1`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Static B14_Value As Long

    If Range("B14") <> B14_Value Then

        ' Save the new B14 value...
        B14_Value = Range("B14")

        ' Fill the formula down on Sheet2. Add one to account for offset.
        Sheet2.Range("A2:H" & B14_Value + 1).FillDown

    End If

End Sub
```

Since you're starting at row 2, we'll need to add 1 to the value of `B14` to account for the offset.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i'll give this a try once I get home!